# Linking the glue code to the test runner class

Tags: eclipse, selenium, gradle, automation, cucumber

I have two different scenarios in the same feature file and for that 2 scenarios I have separate step definitions files but when I run the test runner class, I am not able to link the code to the feature file

First test runner class:-

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"step_def\\Loginstepdef"}, features = "resources",tags={"@SmokeTest"})
public class Test {
}
```

Second Test runner class:-

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"C:\\codes\\LOGIN-Scenarios\\bin\\step_def\\Loginstepdef2.class"}, features = "resources",tags={"@P1_TestCase"})
public class Test2 {
}
```

Comment: Kindly refrain from using words like 'ASAP' or 'urgent' etc. Most of us are here to help out when others are in a tight spot, hoping that the favor is returned when the roles are reversed. The only gain for someone answering is to increase their knowledge. Thanks...

Comment: The glue option is defined in terms of package not in file path. com.glue.....

Comment: we can give address ether in the classpath or in the glue code, I have tried earlier with many codes, it is working fine, no such issue –

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: ok, do you have any solution of this?

Comment: Probably you should pooint the glue to a source file not a compiled .class file. And it is usually a good idea to structure your project so that the step definition files are somehow together or in a logical place.